# Android options menu does not work?

Tags: java, android, callback, android-optionsmenu

I have a single Activity in my project. I created an options menu with 3 items.
I don't know why but it does not work for me. Every time I select an item I get the item ID 0.

**res/menu/m1.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@+id/ITEM1"
        android:title="one">
    </item>
    <item android:id="@+id/ITEM2"
        android:title="two">
    </item>
    <item android:id="@+id/ITEM3"
        android:title="three">
    </item>
</menu>
```

**Activity:**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        menu.add("1");
        menu.add("2");
        menu.add("3");
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch(item.getItemId()){
            case R.id.ITEM01: Toast.makeText(this, "1",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                break;
            case R.id.ITEM02: Toast.makeText(this, "2",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                break;
            case R.id.ITEM03: Toast.makeText(this, "3",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                break;
            default: Toast.makeText(this, "-----",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        }
        Log.v("DEMO", "Item ID: "+item.getItemId());
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

When I select an item I get always 0 in the log. Why?

Answer (score 0):

Replace your onCreateOptionsMenu() method with below code

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.m1, menu);
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace your code by this code

```
 public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
                        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.m1, menu);
                        return true;
                                 }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch(item.getItemId()){
            case R.id.ITEM01: Toast.makeText(this, "1",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                break;
            case R.id.ITEM02: Toast.makeText(this, "2",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                break;
            case R.id.ITEM03: Toast.makeText(this, "3",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                break;
            default: Toast.makeText(this, "-----",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        }
        Log.v("DEMO", "Item ID: "+item.getItemId());
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to inflate the menu to the view

```
 MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
 inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
```

doo this

Comment: @momo : did u get the answer?